# get data from csvdata table how I show branch_name instead of branch_code

Tags: php

I have two tables in a database, i) csvdata, ii)dc_master.
In csvdata table I have some column, as : id ,date, branch_code , A, B, C, D, E, F.
In dc_master table I have three column as: id, branch_code, branch_name
 When get data from csvdata table how I show branch_name instead of branch_code.

Page image link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/zn40pjjai4g92m5/aa.jpg

My code is :

```
<?php 
    include 'include/config.php';
    include 'include/opendb.php';
    include 'loginheader.php'; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CVS Edit</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
-->
</style>

<link href="css/usercss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link type="text/css" href="calendar/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="calendar/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="calendar/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
    var pickerOpts = {
        dateFormat: $.datepicker.ATOM

    };  
    $("#date").datepicker(pickerOpts);

});

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
<!--
.style11 {font-size: 12px}
.style12 {
    color: #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
-->
        </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="date_container">
<form action="cvs.php" method="post" name="date" id="calender" >
  Select a date &nbsp;
  <input name="date2" type="text" id="date" class="required"  />
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="Submit" type="submit" class="submit_button" value="Search" />
</form>
</div>

<div id="cvsdata">
<?php
@$date=$_POST['date2'];

// update data in mysql database

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM csvdata where activity_date like'$date %'ORDER BY `csvdata`.`branch_code` ASC");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

?>
<table width="1456" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id="list">
<tr>
<td colspan="18"><div align="center" class="style3 style11 style11">List of Branches  </div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="81" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Date</span></td>
<td width="70" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Branch Code</span></td>
<td width="74" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Centre</span></td>
<td width="81" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Cash in Hand</span></td>
<td width="64" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Cash at Bank</span></td>
<td width="69" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Member Admitted</span></td>
<td width="68" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Total Member</span></td>
<td width="72" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Total Borrowers</span></td>
<td width="80" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Today Loan Disbursement</span></td>
<td width="74" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Total Loan Outstanding</span></td>
<td width="72" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Today Saving Withdrawn</span></td>
<td width="68" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Total Saving Balance</span></td>
<td width="69" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Total Overdue Member</span></td>
<td width="69" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Total Overdue Amount</span></td>
<td width="75" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Head Office Transaction (+)</span></td>
<td width="75" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Head Office Transaction (-)</span></td>
<td width="60" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Edit</span></td>
<td width="72" align="center" class="style4"><span class="style4 style11 style11">Delete</span></td>
</tr>

<?php
if ($numrows != 0){

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$date='activity_date';


//@$result = mysql_query("SELECT dc_name FROM dc_master where branch_code='001'");
//  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
//  {$centre=$row['dc_name'];}


?>

<tr>
<td height="28" class="readonly"><div align="center" class="style3 style11 style11"><?php echo $rows["$date"]; ?></div></td>
<td class="readonly"><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['branch_code']; ?></span></td>
<td class="readonly"><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['branch_code']; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['A']; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['B']; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['C']; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['D']; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['E']; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['F']; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['G']; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['H']; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['I']; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['J']; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['K']; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['L']; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['M']; ?></span></td>



<!--link to update.php and send value of id -->
<td align="center" class="readonly"><a href="cvsedit.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" class="style3 style5 style5 style11 style11">Edit</a></td>
<td align="center" class="readonly"><a href="delete_cvs.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" class="style3 style5 style5 style11 style11" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete? (After delete you can not undo or get it again) <?php ?>')">Delete</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
}
else {?>

<tr><td colspan="18"><div align="center" class="style3 style11 style11">No record found, Please enter a valid date</div></td></tr> 
<?php }?>
</table>
</div>
<span class="style6 style12">Programmer : Prasanta Baidya / Mobile : 09830980840 / Email id : pbdigit@gmail.com</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, join your two tables:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM csvdata INNER JOIN dc_master ON csvdata.branch_code = dc_master.branch_code where activity_date like'$date %'ORDER BY `csvdata`.`branch_code` ASC");
```

and then display the branch_name

```
<td class="readonly"><span class="style3 style11 style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['branch_name']; ?></span></td>
```

instead of `branch_code`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select * FROM csvdata LEFT JOIN dc_master ON dc_master.branch_code=csvdata.branch_code";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($sar = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)))
{
    echo $sar['branch_name'];
}
```